# Calling a function that returns an array inside a pl/pgsql function. I keep getting null values returned

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Function to be called;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.string_parse_alias_filename(
_input text DEFAULT NULL::text)
RETURNS text[]
LANGUAGE 'sql'

-- given ':myalias:myfilename'  returns ('myalias','myfilename')

AS $BODY$
select * from REGEXP_MATCHES(_input,'^:([[:alnum:]]+):([[:alnum:]]+)(?:$|\.[[:alnum:]]+)?$')
$BODY$;
```

trying to call with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tablelist_id_from_name(
_myname text)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
tfile text[];
BEGIN
select   string_parse_alias_filename(_myname) INTO tfile; --always returns NULL
END
$BODY$  ;
```

When passing ':myalias:myfilename' the function tablelist_id_from_name is not properly returning the array value.  The array variable tfile is always empty.  I used to know how to do this but I'm a bit rusty.

I've tested the string_parse_alias_filename function call by itself and it works fine:
select   * FROM string_parse_alias_filename(':foo:bar');
returns:    (foo,bar)

Comment: You have switched from `sql` to `plpgsql`. 1) `tablelist_id_from_name`, you have not specified a `RETURNS`. Needs to be  `... _myname text) RETURNS text[]` 2) You need to actually return the value. On line after `END` do `RETURN tfile;`. 3) Read [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html).

Comment: FYI, `select string_parse_alias_filename(':foo:bar');` returns: `{foo,bar}` not `(foo,bar)`.

Comment: So I didn’t include all of the second function in order to simplify, but the issue is the call to the sql function.  Can I not call an sal from plpgsql?  Using the debugger to verify, the sql function returns  null.  Callling the Sam sql function on its own works fine.

Comment: 1) Do not leave out bits of code in your question,. It should represent a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 2) See my answer.

Comment: OK, right the return is an array{}, but I'm selecting into an array.  What obvious thing  am I missing?

Comment: In `plpgsql` you have to have an explicit `RETURN <something>` in most cases. See [Returning from a function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) for more information. My answer shows that.

Comment: Loosing my mind.  This literal call inside my pl/pgsql function works:  Select   string_parse_alias_filename( ':foo:bar') INTO STRICT tfile;  while this fails: Select   string_parse_alias_filename( quote_nullable(_myname)) INTO STRICT tfile;  I've tried quote_ident, quote_literal, quote_nullable...

Comment: this works also: Select   string_parse_alias_filename( '' || (_myname) || '') INTO STRICT tfile;

Comment: You changed the issue this means either 1) Create a new question 2) Or update existing question with the complete new code. I point you again at [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Code snippets without context are pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.string_parse_alias_filename(_input text DEFAULT NULL::text)
 RETURNS text[]
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
select * from REGEXP_MATCHES(_input,'^:([[:alnum:]]+):([[:alnum:]]+)(?:$|\.[[:alnum:]]+)?$')
$function$

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tablelist_id_from_name(_myname text)
 RETURNS text[]
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
tfile text[];
BEGIN
select string_parse_alias_filename(_myname) INTO tfile;
RETURN tfile;
END
$function$


select tablelist_id_from_name(':myalias:myfilename');
 tablelist_id_from_name 
------------------------
 {myalias,myfilename}
```

The issue is `public.tablelist_id_from_name` there was no `RETURNS` specified, though I suspect this was a copy/paste error as you would not be able to create function without it. Also there was no `RETURN` of `tfile`. Again not sure how you got a result without it as using the function would error with: *ERROR:  control reached end of function without RETURN*.